Simple Audio Amplifier Solution for MEMS Speaker
I would like to use the MEMS speaker ADAP UT-P2023 from USound (https://usound.com/product/ganymede/). The datasheet recommends the LM48580 ceramic speaker amplifier (class-H), which features an analog input. My processor has a serial audio interface that supports I2S and PDM. I could either use an audio DAC or find a different suitable amplifier with a serial interface. I would really like a simple solution, but so far I have not been able to find a simple audio DAC (e.g. without MCLK) or a suitable piezo driver.
I have looked at the piezo speaker driver DRV5825P from TI, which is a class-D amplifier, whereas the amplifier used in the datasheet (page 7) is a class-H amplifier (enhancement of class-AB). Also, the MEMS speaker requires a DC offset of 15 V (datasheet page 7 and page 16) and I am unsure if that will work with a class-D amplifier.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

This looks a bit like a shopping question which would be off topic. Looking at the TI Piezo speaker drivers/receivers page there is the DRV5825P which has a I2S input. Have you looked at such manufacturer selection guides to try and identify a suitable driver?

@ChesterGillon thanks for your response. Yes, I have looked at the piezo speaker drivers available from TI. I was unsure about the DRV5825P because it is a class-D amplifier, whereas the amplifier used in the datasheet is a class-H amplifier (enhancement of class-AB). Unfortunately, I have never worked with a MEMS speaker, so I am asking for help here. It is not supposed to be a shopping question. The MEMS speaker requires a DC offset of 15 V and I am unsure if that will work with a class-D amplifier.

I also don't have experience of designing for a MEMS speaker. Suggest you [edit] the question to contain your questions about the different classes of amplifier from the previous comment, to help get answers from others.
